# How to get all rows (soft deleted too) from a table in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

To get all rows from a table, I have to use `Model::all()` but (from good reason) this doesn't gives me back the soft deleted rows. Is there a way I can accomplish this with Eloquent?

Answer (score 272, accepted):

To also get soft deleted models

```
$trashedAndNotTrashed = Model::withTrashed()->get();
```

Only soft deleted models in your results

```
$onlySoftDeleted = Model::onlyTrashed()->get();
```

Comment: Link to the docs: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#querying-soft-deleted-models

Comment: Great!!!   https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/how-to-get-soft-deleted-records-in-laravel-5example.html

Comment: How can I include trashed items from relation items?

Answer (score 19):

### Use this to get all record

```
Model::withTrashed()->get();
```

### Use this to get record of particular id

```
Property::withTrashed()->find($list->property_id);
              or
```

> // 1 is unique id of the table

```
 Model::withTrashed()->find(1);
```

Comment: The first part of this answer was already posted. The second part has nothing to do with the question, it is just common Eloquent usage...