# How can i find only deleted rows in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using `SoftDeletes`in my projects, which is recognized as `deleted_at` in database table, I want to search and find only deleted rows.

Here is my controller code

```
 public function trashedJobSearch(Request $request)
{
    $search = $request->get('search');
    $jobs = Jobs::select('id', 'company_name', 'position_name', 'job_description','deleted_at', 'created_at', 'expire_date', 'status')
        ->where(DB::raw('lower(company_name)'), 'like', '%' . mb_strtolower($search) . '%')
        ->orWhere(DB::raw('lower(position_name)'), 'like', '%' . mb_strtolower($search) . '%')
        ->where('deleted_at', '!=', null)
        ->paginate(10);

    return view('/trashed', compact('jobs'));
}
```

I tried to use `onlyTrashed()` but it's not working either.

Comment: can u post the `$search` value, and the record that is deleted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have `orWhere` you need to use a [grouping](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#parameter-grouping) and also `onlyTrashed`

```
Jobs::select('id', 'company_name', 'position_name', 'job_description','deleted_at', 'created_at', 'expire_date', 'status')
  ->where(function ($query) use ($search) {
        $query->where(DB::raw('lower(company_name)'), 'like', '%' . mb_strtolower($search) . '%')
              ->orWhere(DB::raw('lower(position_name)'), 'like', '%' . mb_strtolower($search) . '%');
   })->onlyTrashed()
     ->paginate(10);
```

Comment: sorry I had a typo, it is whereNotNull instead whereNull

Comment: its too not working dude( this code getting only where deleted_at is null. but im need where deleted_at is not null

Comment: I saw the problem, as you have an orWhere you need to do a grouping, I've updated my answer

Comment: this is the reference to the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#parameter-grouping

Comment: before i was finding not deleted rows but with your code now i find nothing ))

Comment: replace whereNotNull with onlyTrashed and also make sure you actually have deleted records that match your search criteria

Comment: i have 3 deleted records and i relaced whereNotNull with onlyTrashed. still not working

Comment: i find nothing.

Comment: then my advice is to install laravel debugbar (https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) and it will tell you the raw query so you can debug.

Answer (score 2):

The `onlyTrashed()` method should work for you. [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent) for Laravel deleted entries.  I have seen times where adding the raw select statement screws it up though.

Take out the extra bits with the `select` and `DB::raw` and then add them in after you have what you need.  Start with the simplest:

```
$testOfDeletedOnlyJobs = Jobs::onlyTrashed()->get();
```

From here, add in the other parts of your query to see where and why it fails.  If the above gives you nothing, perhaps there are no deleted records?

Comment: i just need get deleted rows when im search. i know onlyTrashed() is working but its not working when im searching only deleted rows

Comment: I'd do it the easy way - I'd pull in the deleted rows as above, and then sort on the *collection*.  You know onlyTrashed() works, get all the records and use Laravel to search the collection instead of the database.  (If this isn't too big a data set)

Comment: you are just missing the grouping, check my answer

Comment: i have another page and i collect there only my deleted rows. but when i trying to search in my trashed page there showing only not trashed rows.

Answer (score 2):

You can use 
`Model::onlyTrashed()->get();`

Did you have looking for this post yet?
[How to get all rows (soft deleted too) from a table in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20474439/how-to-get-all-rows-soft-deleted-too-from-a-table-in-laravel)

Comment: have you try `->where(DB::raw('deleted_at IS NOT NULL'))` ? @Rasimoghlu

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

**In your Model-**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class ModelName extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
}
```

**To get  only deleted rows**

```
$search = $request->get('search');
$data = App\ModelName::onlyTrashed()
                ->where('id', $search)
                ->get();
```