# Getting deleted products

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get a list of deleted products, but even though I do have deleted products they not showing up.

Here is my code

```
$products = Product::whereNotNull('deleted_at')->get();
dd($products);
```

Comment: are you using soft deletes?

Comment: yes i'm using soft deletes

Comment: please refer to the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#retrieving-only-soft-deleted-models

Comment: `$products = Product::withTrashed()->get();` or `$products = Product::onlyTrashed()->get();` https://stackoverflow.com/a/20474667/4575350

Comment: @sta `withTrashed` would include non-deleted records

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get all rows (soft deleted too) from a table in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20474439/how-to-get-all-rows-soft-deleted-too-from-a-table-in-laravel)

Answer (score -1):

You can also query like this

```
$products = Product::where('deleted_at', '!=',' ')->get();
```

Comment: The query is working fine Why did you put down voiting to me?

Answer (score -1):

I believe that an appropriate way would be to create a product resource or collection like this:

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'data' => [
            $this->collection->map(function ($product) {
                return [
                    'id' => $product->id,
                    'name' => $product->name,
                    'deleted_at' => $product->trashed(), // Indicate if the product is soft deleted
                ];
            }),
        ]
    ];
}
```

And the controller:

```
$products = Product::onlyTrashed()->get();

        return new ProductCollection($products);
```

The response example in json:

```
{
    "data": [
        [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Otilia O'Connell",
                "description": "Earum saepe repellat autem et expedita odio maxime. Ea dolore labore ea. Consequuntur et saepe quia qui sit quia. Voluptatem veniam fugiat velit vel nobis a ipsum.",
                "price": 29696.84,
                "stock": 1034,
                "image": "https://via.placeholder.com/400x400.png/007777?text=et",
                "deleted_at": true
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

Comment: literally the code is fine, idk why did you put a down voiting.

Comment: I use `Product::onlyTrashed()->get()` that is very useful to you